# FacebookLogin button in Android app using facebook phonegap plugin master

Tags: android, facebook, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using below code in index.js in android app

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
        facebookConnectPlugin.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                alert('Thanks for logging in');
            } else {
                document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
                    'Not authorized';
            }
        });
```

but it gives error **Can't find variable: facebookConnectPlugin**

Please help me anyone.

Thanks all

Comment: Why are you using "===" may be you should use "=="

Comment: In general, you should use === as it checks the type also. In this case, though, it doesn't actually matter, since response.status should be of type String anyways, and if it isn't, it certainly won't equal to String 'connected'.

Comment: i want to know the solution of error: Can't find variable: facebookConnectPlugin.

Comment: That indicates that you haven't installed the plugin correctly. Are you perhaps using PhoneGap Build or CLI? How did you install the plugin int he first place? Did you do [this](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md)?

Comment: I have downloaded facebook phonegap plugin master SDK from GitHub.In Eclipse i have configure this SDK as library project.

Comment: And you did the steps described on my [link](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/blob/master/platforms/android/README.md)? cordova platform add android and so on.

Comment: In CLI, i run cordova -d plugin add /path/to/cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication".it gives error Could not install /path/to/cloned/phonegap-facebook-plugin